# tfListener can't find frames

Tags: urdf, transform-listener, robot-state-publisher, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

in reference to a [previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/1734/use-a-single-static_transform_publisher-for), I wrote this simple urdf file:

```
    <robot name="sonar_platform">

    <!-- base link -->
    <link name="base_link" />
    
    <!-- sonar-ir fixed links -->
    <link name="sonar0_link" />
    <link name="sonar1_link" /> 

    <joint name="sonar0_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="sonar0_link" />
        <origin xyz="1 1 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <joint name="sonar1_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="sonar1_link" />
        <origin xyz="1 -1 0" rpy="0 0 1.57"/>
    </joint>
</robot>
```

Then I use robot_state_publisher to publish the trasforms to tf using a very simple launch file:

```
    <launch>
    <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find sonar_array)/platform_urdf.xml" />
        <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
</launch>
```

Finally, I implemented  a tf listener based on the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "sonar_array");

  ros::NodeHandle node;

  tf::TransformListener listener;

  ros::Rate rate(10.0);
  while (node.ok()){
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    try{
        listener.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/sonar0_link",  
                               ros::Time(0), transform);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
      ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
    }
}
```

but when I try to launch it I get the following error:

```
    [ERROR] [1312225092.766820278]: Frame id /base_link does not exist! When trying to transform between /sonar0_link and /base_link.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::LookupException'
  what():  Frame id /sonar0_link does not exist! When trying to transform between /sonar0_link and /base_link.
Aborted
```

While, if I subscribe the /tf topic i can correctly see the transforms I defined:

```
    transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1312225269
        nsecs: 108000004
      frame_id: /base_link
    child_frame_id: /sonar0_link
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 1.0
        y: 1.0
        z: 0.0
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1312225269
        nsecs: 108000004
      frame_id: /base_link
    child_frame_id: /sonar1_link
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 1.0
        y: -1.0
        z: 0.0
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.706825181105
        w: 0.707388269167
---
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10781/tflistener-can%27t-find-frames/) by [akhernar](https://answers.ros.org/users/914/akhernar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akhernar](https://answers.ros.org/users/914/akhernar/) on 2011-08-01**:
This is just the first output, i checked with view_frames and everything seems ok.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-01**:
One more thing: Is the output you posted just the first output or the total output over time? rosrun tf view_frames can help you get some information.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-01**:
Just a note: You don't need the cat command for the param. Check the ros param syntax for roslaunch, there is an option to load files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would expect it to fail the first couple times through the loop until the transformListener has built up a buffer of data and then start working.

The transformListener subscribes to the /tf topic on construction and cannot provide lookups until it has received enough messages to build up it's tree.

This is at the bottom of this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-01**:
waitForTransform

**Comment by [akhernar](https://answers.ros.org/users/914/akhernar/) on 2011-08-01**:
So do I need to insert a delay between the constructor and the call to lookupTransform? Or should I use waitForTansform?